# How do I save a string to a CSV file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have written code but it will not work. The code is:

```
 #Parse and print the Tweet if the response code was 200
tweets = nil
if response.code == '200' then
tweets = JSON.parse(response.body)
require 'csv'
CSV.open("trial.csv", "ab") do |csv|
  csv << ["text", "created_at", "name", 'id']
  csv << ["tweets"]
  end
end
```

How would I change this code to save the tweets to a CSV text file?

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: I'm seriously fighting the impulse to downvote this for lack of effort. Darn, I'm sure someone will do it now that I've put it out there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are printing the string "tweets", instead I believe you meant to print the value of the variable `tweets`. So the change that is needed is to remove the double quotes around `"tweets"`:

```
CSV.open("trial.csv", "ab") do |csv|
  csv << ["text", "created_at", "name", 'id']
  csv << [tweets]  # <- NOTE the change here 
  end
end
```